# Change Application.ResourceAssembly in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a question that puzzled me.

In beginning, `Application.ResourceAssembly` is null;

```
Application.ResourceAssembly = assembly1;  // it's ok
Application.ResourceAssembly = assembly2;  // It will has a error.
```

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll

So, can `Application.ResourceAssembly` be assigned if it isn't null??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set `Application.ResourceAssembly` twice. You can only set it ONCE.

Here is the MSDN quote from [Application.ResourceAssembly Property page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resourceassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> ResourceAssembly can only be set once because it is unlikely that the resource assembly will change after the WPF assembly is loaded.